# Primefaces dialog keeps focus after being hidden

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

H1 everyone ! Let the following scenario in JSF 2.0 (Mojarra 2.2, Glassfish 4, **Primefaces 4.0**) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body onload="PF('dlg').show()">
        <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg"
            resizable="false" closable="false" >
            <h:form id="form">
                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" /> 
                <p:inputText id="name" />
                <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
                <p:commandButton id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"
                    onclick="alert('ok'); PF('dlg').hide();" />
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The issue is that the Primefaces dialog keeps focus after being hidden : when pressing spacebar or enter key after having canceled the dialog, you can observe that the alert 'ok' will be displayed again!

When trying to set focus out of the dialog using : `onclick="alert('ok'); PF('dlg').hide(); PF('dlg').blur()"` or `onclick="alert('ok'); PF('dlg').hide(); PF('dlg').focusout()"`, it seems that the whole body is reloaded since the dialog reappears...

Am I doing something wrong ? Is it a misconception of mine or a bug in Primefaces ?
Any help will be gratefully appreciated :)

Comment: Try the dialog without the `<h:form/>` and replace the `<p:commandButton/>` with `<p:button/>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer kolossus, but it doesn't work either. Primefaces dialog's keeps on catching spacebar or enter key press after being hidden...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working using:

```
document.activeElement.blur()
```

instead of:

```
PF('dlg').blur()
```